# JavaScript evaluate expression without return in function

Tags: javascript, function, iife

recently due to some backward compatibility issues we had to change our underlying implementation of GraalVM API Javascript Engine which caused some backward compatibility which I would like to address (problem is plain JS related so bear with me). In short, I am wondering if there is any way of writing such a function that would not require a return statement and expression would be sufficient at the end of the function declaration. Here is the code:

```
(function (input) {
  // START
  const { firstSource } = input

  ({
    "firstDestination": firstSource
  })
 //END
})({"firstSource": "input"})
```

The **START -> END** block of code (this is something that can **not be changed** under any circumstances as it is part of the user-defined scripts which have some contracts). I am not a JS expert so any hints would be very helpful as I spent quite some time on IIFE etc but could not come up with any valid solution.

Comment: So you want the `{"firstDestination": firstSource}` to be implicitly returned? That's not possible as far as I know.

Comment: You mean we can add code before START and after END but not in between, and you wish the new code can return last expression of user defined code, am I right?

Comment: @hackape correct

Comment: I guess `eval` can help. But I need to experiment with it.

Answer (score 0):

`eval(code)` API will evaluate whatever code in the local scope, and will also return the last expression as its value even without the `return` keyword. It could be solution you’re looking for.

Example:

```js
function run(input) {
  return eval(`
  // START
  const { firstSource } = input; // I add a semi here, think it’s an error

  ({
    "firstDestination": firstSource
  })
  // END
`)
}

console.log(run({"firstSource": "input"}))
```